# I need to create a dataframe were values reference previous rows

Tags: python, pandas

I am just starting to use python and im trying to learn some of the general things about it. As I was playing around with it I wanted to see if I could make a dataframe that shows a starting number which is compounded by a return. Sorry if this description doesnt make much sense but I basically want a dataframe x long that shows me:

number*(return)^(row number) in each row

so for example say number is 10 and the return is 10% so i would like for the dataframe to give me the series

```
1  11
2  12.1
3  13.3
4  14.6
5  ...
6  ...
```

Thanks so much in advanced!

Comment: @BENY thank you so much. I was trying so hard to make sense out of that single-line number series. Now only I see those were indexes.

Comment: @BENY thank you man, first time using this website. I apologize!

Comment: I think you'd be better off using a loop or a list comprehension _then_ turning it into a `DataFrame`.

Comment: Hey @HenryEcker, I just started learning python yesterday so I dont quite know how to go about that. Could you point me in the direction to learning about loops? thanks!

Comment: I am not sure how `10*(10%)^(1) = 10`.

Comment: @AbhishekPrajapat hey man, yeah my bad I just wrote it to show thats were it started. Ill edit that right now. I need it to start from 11 anyways. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try

```
import numpy as np
val = 10
det = 0.1
n = 4
out = 10*((1+det)**np.arange(n))
s = pd.Series(out)
s
Out[426]: 
0    10.00
1    11.00
2    12.10
3    13.31
dtype: float64
```

Notice here I am using the index from 0 , since 1.1**0 will yield the original value

Comment: you a beast brother. First you help me edit my terribly made post and then you clutch the solution. Thank you sooo much!

Comment: @RafaelRamirez happy coding ~

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'returns': [x for x in range(1, 10)]})
df.index = df.index + 1
df.returns = df.returns.apply(lambda x: (10 * (1.1**x)))
print(df)
```

Out:

```
     returns
1  11.000000
2  12.100000
3  13.310000
4  14.641000
5  16.105100
6  17.715610
7  19.487171
8  21.435888
9  23.579477
```